# SkyDrive not updated to OneDrive on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, onedrive

On one of my Windows 8.1 machine, the SkyDrive is updated to OneDrive - just a name change, nothing else that I notice. But on another one, it's not updated. I tried to check the updates, installed all latest ones, still don't see it updated. Any tricks on how to do this?
Also I notice that the Windows Store app of SkyDrive still has the old name, weird.

Comment: There were no other changes with the name change.  If you still see Skydrive then something isn't right.  Do either of these have the "update 1" installed?

Comment: No, all are proper Windows 8.1, no update 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. As long as you are signed in with a Microsoft account, you are fine.

Microsoft is just a little slow at changing its names so quickly; the same is happening to me.

Eventually, at some point, it will be renamed. They're probably doing Windows 7 first because it is more popular. If you are running Windows XP, you won't receive the update to "Onedrive".

Comment: Hahaha, XP Good riddance!